# Campo do tipo Date do MySQL retornando valor incorreto no Java

Tags: java, mysql

Estou tentando ler os dados de uma tabela do MySQL com o Java, porém o campo do tipo Date está retornando o seguinte código:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1558656000000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT-03:00",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=21,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=23,DAY_OF_YEAR=143,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Este é o método que busca os valores do banco:

```
public List<Contato> getLista() {
        try {
            List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();
            PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM contatos");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Contato contato = new Contato();
                contato.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
                contato.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                contato.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                contato.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));

                Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
                data.setTime(rs.getDate("dataNascimento"));
                contato.setDataNascimento(data); # Retorna a Data

                contatos.add(contato);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            return contatos;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
}
```

E depois chamo no método Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();

        List<Contato> contatos = dao.getLista();

        for (Contato contato : contatos) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + contato.getNome());
            System.out.println("Email: " + contato.getEmail());
            System.out.println("Endereço: " + contato.getEndereco());
            System.out.println("Data de Nascimento: " + contato.getDataNascimento() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pra entender melhor, você gostaria de conseguir exibir a data formatada, por exemplo: 24/05/2019?

Comment: Na linha  `contato.getDataNascimento()` acrescente `getTime()`, ficando assim: `contato.getDataNascimento().getTime()`

Comment: E qual deveria ser o valor correto?

Comment: @GilvanAndré Sim neste formato dd/MM/YYYY

Comment: Obrigado @adventistaa era isso mesmo!

Comment: @hkotsubo dd/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aproveitando o seu código na função getDtNascimento, você pode adicionar o getTime().

Exemplo:

```
Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
data.setTime(rs.getDate("dataNascimento"));
contato.setDataNascimento(data); # Retorna a Data
```

E na hora de chamar você chama assim:

```
System.out.println("Data de Nascimento: " + contato.getDataNascimento().getTime() );
```

Caso queira formatar a data o formato brasileiro pode fazer o seguinte antes:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoBR = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
String newDate = formatoBR.format( contato.getDataNascimento().getTime() );
System.out.println("Data de Nascimento: " + newDate );
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo , funcionou. Muito Obrigado!